# Python - Regex - IP - no result

Tags: python, regex

I wrote some code to extract email and IP addresses from bulk text. However, the code extracts only the email addresses. *(The original text, which I would like to make understandable, is a typical log file)*. I don't know why the generated file does not give me back the IP addresses.

```
import os
import re

# 1
filename = 'errors.txt'
newfilename = 'emaillist-rev.txt'

# 2
if os.path.exists(filename):
    data = open(filename,'r')
    bulkemails = data.read()


else:
    print "File not found."
    raise SystemExit

# 3
r = re.compile(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+')
results = r.findall(bulkemails)    

emails = ""   
for x in results:
    emails += str(x)+"\n"   


# 4
ip = re.compile('^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$')
result = ip.findall(bulkemails)

ip =""
for y in result:
    ip += str(y)+"\n"

# 5
def writefile():
    f = open(newfilename, 'w')
    f.write(emails + ip)
    f.close()
    print "File written."

# 6
def overwrite_ok():
    response = raw_input("Are you sure you want to overwrite "+str(newfilename)+"? Yes or No\n")
    if response == "Yes":
        writefile()
    elif response == "No":
        print "Aborted."
    else:
        print "Please enter Yes or No."
        overwrite_ok()

# 7
if os.path.exists(newfilename):
    overwrite_ok()      
else: 
    writefile()
```

Comment: Replace the anchors with word boundaries - `ip = re.compile(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b')`. Mind you need to use a raw string literal.

Comment: Solved ! Thanks a lot for help :)

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting my answer below in some 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring the `ip` regex, replace the anchors with word boundaries and mind you need to use a raw string literal.

```
ip = re.compile(r'\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b')
```